# VS2013 vs VS2015 single line If...Then

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

The following statement compiles and works in VS2013, but does not in VS2015:

```vb
Dim z As Integer = 1
Dim y As Integer = 2

If z = 1 Then If y = 3 Then 

y = 4
```

The syntax appears to be incomplete, because of the trailing `Then`. I do not know why it would work in VS2013 and not in VS2015.

After execution in VS2013, `y = 4`, so the `Then` statement does not need to cascade to the next line.

Any thoughts as to why? Is this a bug in VS2013?

Comment: @Steve that actually does compile in VS2013. I've just tried it myself.

Comment: Without the End If ?

Comment: @Steve yes, I'm bewildered myself. I've written `Debug.Write(y)` under `y = 4` and it does output 4.

Comment: Oh well, let's see if someone has an explanation then

Comment: I still can't believe it..but i don't have a vs2013 to check

Comment: Hmm..I've tried in VS2010 and it actually compiles!

Comment: It also compiles in VS2015, just tried it.It seems that it's possible, but all the inlined Ifs must be in the same line. For example `If z = 1 Then If y = 2 Then If z = 1 Then y = 5` works and would set `y=5` if `z=1` and `y=2`. The `y=4` part in your code is independent of the Ifs

Comment: @Pikoh so if you removed `y = 5` in VS2015 would it throw up a compile error?

Comment: @Bugs yes, it does not compile.I've tried changing the target framework in case that was the problem, but it does not compile in any framework.

Comment: I actually can't see any use of this. It makes very little sense to me. You can write `If z = 1 Then If y = 3 Then` and then under it you can write a full load of code and it doesn't matter what `z` or `y` equals, the code is still compiled and executed. I assume this was a bug in earlier versions of VS and has now been fixed in VS2015 onwards.

Comment: I agree @Bugs, but it took a lot of time to fix it seems :)

Comment: Weird... 2013 here...   "If A < 1 Then If B < 2 Then" no errors shown, compiles fine, runs and doesn't block, even with nothing after the then. End if on next line cause an error.  If A < 1 Then If B < 2Then C = 3 does set c to a 3

Comment: Madness you can even write `If z = 1 Then If y = 3 Then y = 1 Else` and it compiles just the same. You're not even allowed to append an `End If` as @Trevor has said as that throws a wobbler. I'm going to sit in my box and cry a little.

Comment: I think it ties into this from MSDN... "What follows the Then keyword is examined to determine whether a statement is a single-line If. If anything other than a comment appears after Then on the same line, the statement is treated as a single-line If statement." Once in that mode it stays in that mode. Though as we have seen.. you can chain more IFs. Who knew?

Comment: Roslyn happened, integrated into VS2015.  A complete rewrite of the VB.NET compiler, originally written in C++, now in VB.NET.  Beyond adding a bunch of new bugs, they did take the opportunity to fix bugs in the original compiler.

Comment: @HansPassant, is that a bug or a feature....

Comment: Thanks for confirming I'm not crazy.  I think that @Trevor is probably correct that it stays in the single line mode.   It seems in VS2013, the evaluation after the Then happens once whereas in VS2013, the evaluation happens after every then

Comment: FWIW, in VBA/VB6, `If z = 1 Then If y = 3 Then` results in a syntax error; but `If z = 1 Then If y = 3 Then y = 1 Else` is valid.

Comment: @HansPassant you should write that up as an answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Well,of course Roslyn,that explains it. Thanks @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a 'bug or feature" that got dropped in VS2015...

I suggest you use the more modern

```
    If z = 1 AndAlso y = 3 Then y=4
```